# Google Calendar API on Objective C Issue

Tags: objective-c, google-api, google-calendar-api

i've been working around google calendar API on Xcode (iOS dev), so far i've been able to link my xcode project to my google account, and based on this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-google-calendars--mobile-19155

I finally can POST quick add events to my calendars. However,I'm having issues posting events with specific times.

I build my event string according to:
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/36604?hl=en

_strEventTextToPost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d/%d/%d at %d:%d", _strEvent, [dateComponents day], [dateComponents month], [dateComponents year], [dateComponents hour], [dateComponents minute]];

and posted it using the googleOauth class

[_googleOAuth callAPI:apiURLString
           withHttpMethod:httpMethod_POST
       postParameterNames:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"calendarId", @"text", nil]
      postParameterValues:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[_dictCurrentCalendar objectForKey:@"id"], _strEventTextToPost, nil]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[_dictCurrentCalendar objectForKey:@"id"], _strEventTextToPost, nil]);

When I run the app, the event get posted in the calendar, but as an all day event, i've tried changing the string order but always appears without Hour/Minute.

Any additional information please comment below, thank you! i'm quite stuck right now!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried "on 2014/05/24 at 13:30" and it worked so try prepending "on" before the date.

You can play with it in the "Try it" section here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/quickAdd